# Python - Can I Instert A String Into The Open Function, Somehow...?

Tags: python, function

So, I've got this string

```
string="name random or not"
```

(it's easy to add a ".txt" ending in this)

and I want to create a file with this name to use it as an output. But when I write this:

```
output = open( '%s' , 'w'  % (string) )
```

or this:

```
output = open( '%s' , 'w'  % (string) )
```

I get "invalid syntax" and "not all arguments converted during string formatting" errors respectively.

Is there a way this could work?

Comment: Why don't you pass `string` directly?

Answer (score 1):

Functions have arguments, and each argument can be an expression; an expression is `'%s' % string`:

```
output = open('%s' % (string), 'w')
```

Comment: I'd guess the user actually wants `'%s.txt' % string`, and this answer is probably best to get them there.

Answer (score 1):

Or more simply

```
output = open(string,'w')
```